# Plotting vectors/arrows at points parallel to given vector

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with 3d coordinates and normalized vectors. I need to plot these vectors at these given points. I know I can use vector algebra to find the "to" points to plot the arrows with the "from" points listed as the coordinates. But is there any shortcut to do this directly in gnuplot maybe using vectors and not arrows?

Sample data:

x       y       z       Vx       Vy       Vz

4.96107    4.6534   3.49518 -0.6864  0.0575 -0.7249

2.95447    4.54705  5.19762 -0.8473  0.5311 0

2.95447    4.54705  1.18888 -0.974  -0.2265 0

Comment: `splot "FILENAME" with vectors`?

Comment: Thank you @user8153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector styles in gnuplot expect data in the form

```
x y x_delta y_delta
```

for 2d plots.  The vectors will be drawn from (x,y) to (x+Δ<sub>x</sub>, y+Δ<sub>y</sub>).

Similarly, for 3d plots, you can use data in the form

```
x y z x_delta y_delta z_delta
```

where the vectors go from (x,y,z) to (x+Δ<sub>x</sub>, y+Δ<sub>y</sub>, z+Δ<sub>z</sub>).  In this case, your data is exactly the second case.  You can do `splot "file" with vectors` to plot your data (use `plot` for 2d data or `splot` for 3d data).  This produces<sup>**†**</sup>

[image: Plot with vectors]

We can even customize the arrow heads.  For example `splot "file" with vectors filled` produces filled arrow heads.

[image: filled arrow heads]

`splot "file" with vectors nohead` removes the arrow heads altogether.

[image: no arrow heads]

Very fine control of the arrow heads is possible.  See `help vectors` and `help arrowstyle` for more details.

---

<sup>**†**</sup> Because your file has column labels on the first line, I issued `set key autotitle columnhead` to notify gnuplot of this, and tell it to not plot the first line.  Without this, you will get an error message 
`warning: Bad data on line 1 of file data.txt` (where I have saved your data in the file *data.txt*).  I also issued `unset key` to prevent the plotting of a key in these graphs.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, I tried to search using vectors on gnuplot but it didn't help.. seems like this is trivial..